# How to import functions of a jupyter notebook into another jupyter notebook in Google Colab

Tags: import, google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I would like to import functions of a Jupyter notebook (ending   .ipynb) into another Jupyter notebook.

Both notebooks are located in Google Drive in the same file. The notebook in which the functions of the other notebook should be imported, is already open in Google Colab.

Therefore I'm looking for a code snipped like

```
from  xxx.ipynb  import functionX
```

I have already installed the PyDrive wrapper and authenticated and created the PyDrive client like follows:

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `import_ipynb` library.

First, mount your google drive to access your xxx.ipynb

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("mnt")
```

Then change directory to the notebook directory.

```
%cd "mnt/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
```

Now install the `import_ipynb` library, and import it

```
!pip install import-ipynb
import import_ipynb
```

Now you can import your `xxx.ipynb`

```
import xxx
xxx.do_something()
```

Here's an [example Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nta1E1GbvWw0NknSNhpMPrH39af3HMhj).

### Update (oct 2020)

I have made the process easier, by just installing `kora` and call a function.

(Please also use [auto-mount](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1226929213560610818?s=20) in a new notebook)

```py
!pip install kora -q
from kora import drive
drive.link_nbs()
```

Now you can import from any notebooks you made before. For example, if you already have `mylib.ipynb` you can

```py
import mylib
mylib.do_something()
```

Comment: Is there any other solutions without mounting the derive?

Comment: I was previously doing this: I would convert and download my `My_Custom_Functions.ipynb` as `my_custom_functions.py` and reupload it back to my drive Colab Notebooks. This was a long story and I did not like but it stopped working at `!pip install one_module`. This failed. After searching, I found your answer. Surprisingly, it worked like a cham. Thanks a lot for saving my time and new lesson.

Comment: I'm trying the first approach, I can import the file, but when it comes to calling the function. For example A.function_call(), I get the following: AttributeError: module 'A' has no attribute 'function_call'

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

1. Mount Google Drive
2. Install the `ipynb` module
3. `cd` to your working directory
4. Run `from ipynb.fs.defs.<the notebook name> import <the things you want to import>`

Example:

```
!pip install ipynb
%cd /your/working/directory
from ipynb.fs.defs.notebook_to_import import class1, class2, func1, func2
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can follow below method without changing the directory:

```
source_path_file = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Works/functions.ipynb'
source_path_file = source_path_file.replace(' ', '\\ ')

!cp $source_path_file '/content' # to copy the file from drive to colab

!rsync -aP $source_path_file '/content/functions.ipynb' # run this line to sync with the parent file in case you made any changes

import import_ipynb
import functions as fn
#as i'm importing functions.ipynb in my case
```

If you want to import functions file without mounting to drive. You are gonna have to import the functions file from some where and you can follow above from 'imports sections'.