# Google Colab: Call a function from another python file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to run a function `DataProcesser` from a `load_data.py` python file, which can be found in my google drive path `gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/CODEX/source/`.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

# Custom functions/classes
path_to_module = 'gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/CODEX/source/'  # Path where all the .py files are, relative to the notebook folder
sys.path.append(path_to_module)
from load_data import DataProcesser
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-30-066e93c75b7d> in <module>()
>      20 path_to_module = 'gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/CODEX/source/'  # Path where all the .py files are, relative
> to the notebook folder
>      21 sys.path.append(path_to_module)
> ---> 22 from load_data import DataProcesser
>      23 from train_utils import even_intervals
>      24 from models import *
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'load_data'
> 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
> manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
> 
> To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
> "Open Examples" button below.
> -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to escape the spaces in your string `path_to_module` but it might be that the path Colab sees is different. If you expand the `files` tab in Colab you can navigate to the files in Google Drive. Then you can right click on the file or folder you want and do `Copy path`. You can then paste this into the cell where `path_to_module` is defined.

Suffice to say, it works for me; but my path (`.../tmp`) will be different to yours.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
import sys    
path_to_module = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/tmp'
sys.path.append(path_to_module)
from mypy import myfunc
```

I navigated to the `tmp` folder and copied the properties which I then pasted into the code.

Comment: @melololo Feel free to accept this answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple technique is change the directory of execution. Even though you have mounted the *Google Drive* the execution doesn't  take place in that drive. It takes place in `/content/`. YOu can check this by running `pwd`. Change this by running `cd path_to_ the_python_file_where_function_is_defined`. Then do `import name_of_the_file`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then

```
libdir = "/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/.../"
%run {libdir}MyModule.py
```

Similarly, you can do with notebooks:

```
%run {libdir}MyNotebook.ipynb
```

Now you can use all you have defined in MyNotebook.ipynb