# Google colab: python packages are not imported from google drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, python-import, site-packages

I have a problem with importing packages from my Googly Drive in colab:

[image: imported packages not shown]

Python Version is Python 3.10.12.

I tried [this "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66267458/3116388) among others (see screenshot: I used `PYTHONPATH` there", but the package "Ebooklib0.1" is not shown in `pip list -v` (see screenshot)