# Getting access to python function from another python .ipynb file in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to import a function from a .ipynb file, but I'm not having much joy. So to be clear a new colab file should be able to call the file that contains the function. But I'm failing to get this to work. Below is the code I'm using.

One file is named `Summary.ipynb` (with function to call named create)
`Generate.ipynb` is calling that function

```
from google.colab import drive
import sys

drive.mount('/content/drive')
sys.path.insert(0,'/content/drive/folders/XXXX')
from Summary import create
```

Gives the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Summary'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import functions of a jupyter notebook into another jupyter notebook in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020008/how-to-import-functions-of-a-jupyter-notebook-into-another-jupyter-notebook-in-g)

Comment: Briefly, what you are doing would work if you were importing from a `.py` file, but there's a little bit more complexity in importing functions from an `.ipynb` notebook. Have a look at the answers to the linked question.